# Regarding Resistance SPOT WELDING OF Nickel 0.2mm to Al of 1mm by precision spot welding machine

Tags: research

Sir,

I want to weld 0.2mm Nickel to 1 mm of Al by overlapping welding by resistance spot welding of Precision micro welding machine for Li ion battery application. so, pl suggest me some welding parameters.

our machine has maximum Current of 0-99 Amperes ; time- 1 to 3 Cycels ; force - 0.5 kg to 3.5 Kg.

so, pl suggest me some welding parameters.

This is the machine we are using sir.

[image]